# how to print a string into a function?

Tags: r

How I can put the variable "diti" inside the function specifyModel?

```
> diti
[1] " + mySMI(GSPC) + myCLV(GSPC) + myMACD(GSPC) + myrunMean(GSPC)"
data.model <- specifyModel(T.ind(GSPC) ~ Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1) diti )
Error: unexpected symbol in "data.model <- specifyModel(T.ind(GSPC) ~ Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1) diti"
```

it is seposed to look like this:

```
data.model <- specifyModel(T.ind(GSPC) ~ Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1) + mySMI(GSPC) +    myCLV(GSPC) + myMACD(GSPC) + myrunMean(GSPC) )
```

Thanks,

Alon

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment by @josilber, the argument passed to the function `specifyModel()` needs to be concatenated with `paste` into a single character string.

In your example this could be achieved with

```
data.model <- specifyModel(paste("T.ind(GSPC) ~ Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1)",diti))
```

or

```
data.model <- specifyModel(eval(paste("T.ind(GSPC) ~ Delt(Cl(GSPC),k=1)",diti)))
```